# Delete from a webview without selecting?

Tags: javascript, ios, richtextbox

I have a webview in my app in which I am typing text. For deleting the same text I am using the following commands:

```
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand('selectall')"];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.execCommand('delete')"];
```

Is there any way to directly delete everything without selecting? I dont have much knowlegde about javascript.
Thanks

Comment: shouldn't "selectall" select all the webview's content? what is your problem exactly?

Comment: selectall selects and delete deletes all content.. thats fine.. but I am looking for a way to achive this without selecting all the content.. That looks ugly and probably is not the best way to go about it.

Comment: could you paste the definition of `selectall`?

Comment: here are all the commands I know of richtext:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla